Make the "Save to" dialog draggable
The dialog that opens when you save a post then click "manage" on the notification isn't draggable unlike other dialogs like the one that opens when you are about to flag something.
For reference, this is the dialog i'm talking about

Can it be made draggable?

There was a problem with dragging these dialogs when the Saves feature was launched which I reported here and the fix that was implemented was to make the dialogs not draggable.
